# python tensorflow: How to avoid giving feed_dict to every sess.run()?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Let say I want to find the centroids using the KMeans method.

For the first iteration, I would like to use initFirstCentroids to get some sample data from the dataset X.

Before the second iteration, the user can see the first iteration result and input the initial centroids for the second iteration.

In the static graph, the input is defined as tf.placholder(tf.float32,shape=(None,D)). As the number of points is unknown, I cannot make it as a tf.Variable

When I need to call the sess.run() to calculate, it always ask me to provide the feed_dict, but actually my dataset is not changed. Can I just give the input once (like using tf.Variable)

```
# k=3, centroids is a tf.Variable 
dataset=np.array([[1.,2.],[3.,4.],[5.,6.],[7.,8.],[2.5,5.2],[6.6,4.4]])
With tf.Session() as sess:
    # the feed_dict is the same for the entire session. can I just input once?
    sess.run(init)
    sess.run(initFirstCentroids, feed_dict={X:dataset})
    for i in range(10):
        centroids_value=sess.run(iter_centroids,feed_dict={X:dataset})
        print(centroids_value)
        userInput=input()  # say I can input [ [2.,5.],[3.,3.],[6.5,6.] ]
        userArray=np.array(userInput,np.float)
        assign_userInput=tf.assign(centroids,userArray)
        sess.run(assign_userInput,feed_dict={X:dataset})
```

Comment: Is you dataset known actually known statically?

Comment: Instead of using a placeholder, maybe you can just use the values from the dataset directly?